# enable VNC to run on an account different than the current account on mac

Tags: windows, mac, vnc, screen-sharing

How can I make my MAC VNC server to which many windows based PCs can connect simultaneously with distributed access to resources.

I want to share my MAC with multiple users using Windows, can I do that somehow?

Comment: The VNC tools I've used haven't assumed any relationship between accounts on client or server computers... are you sure there's an actual problem here?

Comment: seemingly yes. When i am using account Y, the vnc shows me the desktop for account Y, whereas i want it to show me the screen for account X. there is no option for me to choose what account i want to see.

Comment: you want to share Windows screen to multiple MACs/Windows?

Comment: mac screen on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you achieve what you want but once I had to share my MAC with multiple windows based PCs and I had setup VineVNC on every MAC user account with on different ports.

On the other side the Windows based PCs was having TightVNC to connect to the single MAC user account. Every windows was connected to different user on MAC and it was real MAC sharing.

You can also call it 3 person was using a single mac like they were using their own.

Comment: so u were not using leopard built in vnd sharing?

Comment: No I didn't. I tried but it was worthless with no specific documentation as how to do this.

Comment: Also, there were some disconnections time and again and I couldn't find the cause.